# Add and remove class from multiple jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I want to change background from parents element when one of the radio button is checked.

But I need it to works on multiple elements like Post review, Post comment etc, (this templates has common html structure with the same css selector **vendor-reply-bot** ).

Here is my code: (now works only for #VendorReviewAbuse)

```
 // Change background on report abuse 
 // =================
 $('.vendor-reply-bot input').click(function() {

     var $els_Checked = $("#VendorReportCommentAbuse:checked, #VendorReportReviewAbuse:checked");
     var $els_NotChecked = $("#VendorReportCommentAbuse:not(:checked), #VendorReportReviewAbuse:not(:checked)");

     $els_NotChecked.parents(':eq(1)').removeClass("abuse");
     $els_Checked.parents(':eq(1)').addClass("abuse");
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like this:

```
$els_NotChecked.each(function(){
    $(this).parents(':eq(1)').removeClass("abuse");
});
```